# Setting the default submit button without an asp:panel

Tags: asp.net

I have a page with user controls getting dynamically added. Inside some of these user controls there are form elements, either simple `<input>` tags or complex third party controls (Telerik RadDatePicker for example) (technical details at end).

These controls are currently being identified as part of the same form based on a ValidationGroup string setting. My question is how can I get these form elements to submit on `Enter` together and raise the right postback event?

I cannot use the DefaultButton panel property because I don't have the id of the submit button available within the controls server-side. I think I might be able to use jquery clientside like this:
`<input onKeyPress="javascript:if (event.keyCode == 13) {$(this).change(); $('#submitclientid').click();}" ...>`

But I don't know how to do that for the third party controls.

Further technical details:
Each form element is in a separate DNN module. Inter-module communication can be used to pass around data server side which results in multiple modules working together as part of a single logical form on a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the only way to do this is via client side JS as suggested in the question (you can however skip the jquery and instead use `__dopostback`).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `DefaultButton` property of `Form`?

Example:

```
<form defaultButton="myButtonControl" runat="server">
...
</form>
```

Comment: Cannot do. There may be multiple default buttons for separate forms that happen to be on the same page.

Comment: I think I might be misunderstanding: how can a single form have *multiple* default buttons? The purpose of DefaultButton is to have a single button act as the default button for the object to which it is attributed. You can have multiple forms - each with their own distinct DefaultButton - but I don't think it's possible (or even common?) to have multiple DefaultButtons. 

In client-side script, the property you'd probably want (if you want to take care of assigning the default buttons yourself, which it sounds like you'll have to if you want more than one per form), is .ClientID.

Comment: 1. I have no access to the form control.
2. There is only one form control on the page and I cannot add another.
3. It is perfectly possible to set multiple default buttons via a <asp:panel runat="server" defaultbutton="id_of_default_button_for_postback" ...> tag. I however cannot do this either because I cannot set the id (nor can I surround the controls with the panel because they are being dynamically added to the page by the framework).
4. I could use the client id, but do not know how to with the third party controls (though I suspect this is the only solution, so I must learn how)

Answer (score 0):

By code.

aspx:
1 form (form1), 2 buttons (Button1 & Button2)

aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   form1.DefaultButton = Form.FindControl("Button2").UniqueID;
}
```